# Ajax parsexml without jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, gmail

I have a piece of code to get the unread count of Gmail. It is using jQuery, and I would like to know how to do it without a Javascript library, just with Javascript.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
  var result = $(xml).find("fullcount").text();
  alert("count:" + result);
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

Comment: This is a legitime question, but someone give hin a -1..

Comment: @GabrielSantos The text bubble that appears when the down arrow is hovered over, states "This question does not show any research effort, <some other stuff>".  This question does indeed, not show any research effort, as a simple google search shows tons of results, aside from this site.

Comment: @Daedalus I think the user done some researches, as I have done, to know if he has done.

Comment: @GabrielSantos [Javascript ajax](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ajax), [javascript parse xml](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+parse+xml).  Third result, and second result respectively.  Question doesn't show research.

Comment: @Daedalus I'm sorry, but here my first Google page have nothing similar to this. Maybe because of country or search history, but, nothing related.

Comment: Unless u dont have a courage to give a comment, dont give -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, Solved

```
xhrGmail = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrGmail.open('GET','https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom')
xhrGmail.onload = function() { console.log(xhrGmail.responseText.split("<fullcount>")   [1].split("</fullcount>")[0]) }
xhrGmail.send(null);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. I'm using Firefox v29 and can navigate to https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom to see the xml no problems. Any ideas why the code might not be working?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://mail.google.com");
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom",false,"username","pwd");
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
var mailCount=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry").length;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get an error in console: Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11. I think you need username and password in your script? that is not needed in the code I posted.